# Apache do not follow symlinks

Tags: magento2, apache, symlinks

Hosting - Amazon
Mangeto 2.3.2
Apache

In developer mode, Magento creates symlinks in pub static directory, but when Magento try include static files on a page it responds with 403 error. 
I have tried change permissions to all files to 777, change owner but it doesn't work .htaccess files is the default.
Now I generate static files with `php bin/magento s:s:d` but I should have a possibility to use symlinks.
I will be appreciated for any advice.

Comment: 1) You're not running those commands that regenerate files as root are you? If you do `ls . -dl` in the public files directory, is the Magento user the owner still?

2) What does your config look like for the directory? Do you have FollowSymLinks like `Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews`

Comment: @ErikB 1) All files generated with root:root owner, but even when I change it to www-data:www-data and run chmod -R 777 ./ problem exists. 2) Magento .htaccess is not changed, it looks like apache is configured for using symlinks i.imgur.com/hfm1wM1.png, and in Plesk I unselect checkbox to allow use symlinks. i.imgur.com/SfC04is.png